# How to add a user to a private channel only by invitation link in Discord?

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

Hello I have a public server and a private channel in it.
I need to provide a link for specific users to make them be included in the private channel.
No one will be included in the private channel apart from who've received that link or those who will be invited manually from us.
I tried dyno bot but it seems not to work properly for what I need.
Is there a way to accomplish what I need?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

In discord every channel has a unique invite link! You can use that to make an **object/dict** that has: `id`, `role_id` and `invite_links:list`, and by using [`discord.on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) you can get the invite code using [`discord.abc.GuildChannel.invites`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invites#discord.abc.GuildChannel.invites) and [`discord.Invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invites#discord.Invite). Then just loop through the `invite_links` list u've created in your **object/dict** and if it's in there then give your member the `role_id`.

**REFERENCES**

- [This is a medium article that shows you how to find the invite code of a user](https://medium.com/@tonite/finding-the-invite-code-a-user-used-to-join-your-discord-server-using-discord-py-5e3734b8f21f).